# how to use firebase without trusting a remote server's javascript?

Tags: javascript, security, firebase

I've had a look at Firebase it looks like an outstanding server push option. I just have a security concern.

With my application security is extremely important - malevolent JavaScript code running in the customer's browser can cause a significant financial loss.

I'd like to have the option of loading the JavaScript from our server directly - and then connect to (i assume) Firebase's websocket infrastructure for messaging.

The browser would not trust or run javascript from any domain aside from ours - but still maintain external websocket connections to Firebase.

I've been through the documentation but couldn't see this explicitly discussed.

TIA

ps: I suspect perhaps it's possible with Access-Control-Allow-[Origin|Method|Headers] ?
pps: I'm not concerned about firebase's reputation or trustworthiness etc. It's just that security is so important to this app that loading JavaScript from another domain is just one more unacceptable attack vector. Our policy is to avoid loading JavaScript from -any- external domains.

Comment: You can simply download the firebase.js file and serve it from your own server. Or you can install it from bower. You don't need to use the one on our CDN.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Andrew, using Bower to download and include the Firebase library as part of your web app would be the best solution in this case.